# C++ inline function and external function with the same name give an unexpected result

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule

Following code do not violate One Definition Rule, yet it is giving an unexpected result:

**Test.hpp**

```
class Test
{
    public:
        int test();
};
```

**Test1.cpp**

```
#include "Test.hpp"

int Test::test()
{
    return 1;
}

int test1() // expected to return 1
{
    Test a = Test();
    return a.test();
}
```

**Test2.cpp**

```
#include "Test.hpp"

inline int Test::test() // doesn't violate ODR
{
    return 99;
}

int test2() // expected to return 99
{
    Test a = Test();
    return a.test();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

int test1();
int test2();

int main()
{
    std::cout << test1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << test2() << std::endl;
}
```

I am expecting it to print "1 99", but it always prints "1 1".

Regarding two definitions of Test::test, since one of them is an inline definition, it does not violate One Definition Rule as well.

So this program is valid, but it is not printing out expected result...

Is there anything wrong with this program? Or am I misunderstanding something about ODR rule? (a reference to C++ standard would be helpful).

Comment: `Regarding two definitions of Test::test, since one of them is an inline definition, it does not violate ODR` Where did you get this idea?

Comment: Well, i think it does not violate ODR, since this issue is not mentioned under ODR section in the C++ specification. "If a function with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required." is mentioned in function specifier section, which doesn't deal with ODR.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to define the function as both `inline` and non-`inline`.

> If a function with external linkage is
>   declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears;
>   no diagnostic is required.

([dcl.fct.spec]/4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the statement you mentioned is not stated in ODR section of the specification. So can I say that the code I presented doesn't violate ODR? (it violates function specifiers rule, but not ODR)

Comment: @SHH I can't say whether or not it does. The wording of the ODR has "non-inline function". It therefore implicitly assumes that a function cannot be both inline and non-inline; it must be one or the other. The ODR doesn't even make sense when you try to declare the same function as both inline and non-inline.